# Are there any limitations to using ROS in VirtualBox Ubuntu?

Tags: ros, ubuntu, virtualbox, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 on VirtualBox on Mac OS X Yosemite and I then installed ROS Indigo on Ubuntu.

I am wondering if there are any features of ROS that this setup does not allow, such as connecting to hardware like sensors or actuators.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212848/are-there-any-limitations-to-using-ros-in-virtualbox-ubuntu?/) by [loubohan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23047/loubohan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, maybe you could have problems with USB devices (USB 3.0). I just know that USB 2.0 devices are supported only by this plugin. But maybe USB 3.0 is supported as well, but you would have to check for that and I am in doubt that you need USB3. Most kind of stuff I guess will work, even serial interfaces can be bound to the virtual machine.

I have used it multiple times to simulate multi machine setups on one computer. I did not experience any problem so far.

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1